# Removing duplicates between the two lists while maintaining the duplicates in one specific list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently creating my program regarding data structures using Python 2.7.13 and I find it hard to finish it. With this, i want to remove all the duplicates between the two lists while maintaining the duplicate elements in one specific list considering that it is not the same with the other list.

To make it clear, I will be presenting an example,
Suppose:

input:

```
    a= [1,2,2,5,6,6]
    b= [2,5,7,9]
```

expected output:

```
    c= [7,9,1,6,6]
```

Comment: This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Where is **your code**, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried coding in python 2.7 but unfortunately i cannot achieve the expected output i want (c= [7,9,1,"6,6"], as shown in the example), in which the duplicates in variable "a" will be maintained. I've attempted to do it and tried several functions in coding but i always end up into getting an output of (c=[7,9,1,"6"]. what should i do then?

Comment: You should learn [ask] and put a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: Okay sir. Sorry, since this is my first time to ask such question in this website and I'm still a newbie in the world of coding. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the symmetric difference for 2 sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can start with

```
>>> set(a).intersection(set(b))
 {2, 5}

>>> set(a).union(set(b)) - set(a).intersection(set(b))  
 {1, 6, 7, 9}
```

Let us say you have a set called `common`

```
common = list(set(a).union(set(b)) - set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

Then you can find your list as:

```
>>> [c for c in (a+b)  if c in common]
[1, 6, 6, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Finally, I got to finish my program. By the way, do you know any references that has something to do with "Food recipe program"-- in which one can input the amount of a specific ingredient or anything like that? Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Good answer, you can make it even shorter by using the symmetric difference.

Comment: @itsjay Sorry I have no idea about a 'food recipe program'.

Comment: @Elmex80s: Thanks for the comment. It looks exactly like what itsay needs!